# In reactjs, multiple api calls in a single component making unnecessary rendering due to state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [MusicData, setMusicData] = useState(null)
const [TopArtistsdata, setTopArtists] = useState(null)

const getMusic = async () =>{
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(URL)
            setMusicData(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error fetching data")
        }
    }

const getTopArtists = async () =>{
        try {
            const responseOfArtists = await axios.get(URL)
            setTopArtists(response.data.artists.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error,"error fetching data")
        }
    }

useEffect(() => {
            getMusic()
        
            getTopArtists()
        }
        
    }, [])
```

I pass these two states to two child components. the 1st one load but the 2nd one is showing error because it was null in 1st render. Console.log(TopArtistsdata) shows "null" two times and 3rd time data is fetched. So technically the parent component is rerendering 3 times. 1st two times the 2nd state was null. I dont understand where is the problem.

Comment: Why do you need to do 2 requests for this? The response of the `getMusic` axios call already has the artist data inside it right? (the reason it renders 3 times is the initial render plus the 2 other state setting calls when the API calls resolve)

Comment: @Jayce444 Because later i will add interval to getTopArtists every 1min but not getmusic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for three renders are listed below :

1. Initial render (1st render with initial values i.e null)
2. Lets assume getMusic call succeeded then it will do setState (2nd render with MusicData having value and TopArtistsdata as null)
3. Now if getTopArtists succeeds then it will again render (#rd render with MusicData having value and TopArtistsdata having value)

If you don't want to render children with and error, Keep the initial values inside state with whatever is expected with child components.

If you have two state variables then this re-rendering is expected.
You can minimize using either making use of promise.all